# Async/await pausing concept

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Let's say we have two Async functions:

```
function someOtherAsyncFunc() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve()
            }, 3000)
        }) 
}


async function asyncFunc() {
    const asyncData =  await someOtherAsyncFunc()
    console.log("sync task that doesn't depend on the asynchronous data")
    asyncData.doSomething()
}
```

Is there a way not to pause the function execution until only the asynchronous variable is referenced later on in the code?

- Get the asynchronous data asynchronously
- Continue the execution until that data is needed and then 'await' it

Comment: No, there is not a way to do that.

Comment: Just don’t await. Await when you actually want to suspend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just declare the Promise alone without extracting the value from it - only extract the value from it once you actually need it.

```
async function asyncFunc() {
    const asyncDataPromise = someOtherAsyncFunc()
      // .catch(handleErrors)
      // catching would be nice to see here, though probably not strictly necessary
      // if the rest of the code is completely synchronous and won't return before awaiting
    console.log("sync task that doesn't depend on the asynchronous data")
    (await asyncDataPromise).doSomething()
}
```

But if the other code in question is synchronous, it would often make more sense from a code organization perspective to only make the async request once you want to wait for it.

```
async function asyncFunc() {
    console.log("sync task that doesn't depend on the asynchronous data")
    const asyncData =  await someOtherAsyncFunc()
    asyncData.doSomething()
}
```

Comment: I want the JavaScript engine to start on the asynchronous task, and while it's getting that data, work on the synchronous code.

And then only pause when the data in question is needed.

This, in case the asynchronous task finishes before the data is needed; then the engine didn't have to pause execution at all and used the time it would have been paused to process synchronous code.

Comment: @Elbasel the "starting" of the asynchronous task will take no time at all. You can start it any time, and it won't make a difference.

Comment: @Elbasel While it's theoretically possible that sending out the request first could result in less time spent overall, the vast majority of synchronous code is *cheap* and takes essentially no time at all to execute. Making the request and storing the Promise in a variable would only be possibly useful if the synchronous code is expensive, which is quite unusual in my experience - so `const asyncData =  await someOtherAsyncFunc()` will suffice almost all the time.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, but once I start it, the execution will pause.

I guess a better choice of words would be to "work" on the asynchronous task instead of "start" in my previous comment.

I don't want the execution to be paused while the asynchronous task is running, but then only pause when it's return data is needed.

Comment: That's only of a concern if your synchronous task(s) are expensive, which is pretty unusual.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I guess this will only come in handy only in that corner case, thanks.

Comment: @Elbasel no, the execution will not pause.

Comment: You should generally avoid the former pattern - if the "sync task" throws an exception, the promise is no longer handled and can crash your application if it rejects. So make sure that never happens - either by adding a `.catch()` on the promise before starting the sync task, or by putting the sync code in a `try`/`catch`.